# Debian 9.13 end of life and Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, debian, debian-stretch

I have a Magento 1.9 store running on Debian 9.13. I know Debian 9 will reach the End of Life in June 2022. If I don't update both Debian and Magento, could be they run "forever"?

What should I do? I'm developing my Magento 2 store but in the meanwhile...

Comment: Running for ever: yes, But never do it, especially on a internet connected computer, and especially on things attached to the web. Every webserver is scanned several times per day to find vulnerabilities. And for sure it is not a good visit card not caring about security (especially on PHP)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi you 're right. But this is just for few other months. I'm planning to replace Magento 1 with Magento 2 on early 2023.

Answer (score 0):

It still runs but there will be no further updates or upgrades.
You should upgrade your website to Magento 2. In the Magento version, there will be many updates and especially it supports more features than Magento 1.